# Start OneDrive on multiple remote systems

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to check if the process is running and if the process is not running, start OneDrive.exe. I tried:

```
$newProc = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "OneDrive"
$newProc.Arguments = 'explorer.exe $pathToOneDrive'[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProc)
```

The problem is OneDrive error

> OneDrive can't be run using full administrator rights

I tried the `-runas` which did not work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Was OneDrive installed in per-user or per-system mode? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/per-machine-installation . Do you want it to run as the currently logged-in user, or as your admin/remoting account?

Comment: OneDrive was installed in the per-user mode. I want it to run as the currently logged-in user.